# How do I create transparent, 8bit shadows for further use in Photoshop?

Tags: rendering, color-management, render-passes

I'm struggling with a problem. I created a simple scene in Blender:

[image]

As you probably guess, I want to use that scene to create a mockup in Photoshop. The goal is to have a separate shadow that will blend with the background in Photoshop. However, after exporting different layers in PNG format, I get this ugly result:

[image]

Shadows are denser and have those ugly highlights in some areas. I've spent a lot of time figuring out what's the problem: 32bit linear color mode in Blender vs. 8bit Photoshop. After changing color mode to 32bit in Photoshop, it looks better, but still not perfect. Also, 32bit mode makes the image almost impossible to edit since PS has a limited set of tools that are working in that mode. Multilayer EXR also fails (it still operates in 32 bit mode).

Do you know how to solve this problem? Almost 99% percent of mockups on the market have separate shadows, so I guess it can be achieved:

[image]

Comment: Shadows are captured linearly in Blender. The way apps like Photoshop work however, assume the values are nonlinearly encoded. The only way I know of is to (brutal horrible hack do not do this is bad advice never do this) nonlinearly encode your alpha (I warned you dammit!) for use in nonlinear apps like Photoshop. As for that peculiar shadow fold region, no idea, but the dirty nonlinear encoding of alpha should work.